# NetBeans Maven Project jar file not executing

Tags: netbeans, deployment, jar, pom.xml

For some reason when I clean and build my maven project in NetBeans, the resulting jar file does not execute when clicked. I've tried altering the pom file several times, here is what it looks like now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>mainWindow.java</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>                         
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
    <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
      <id>corp1</id>
      <name>Corporate Repository</name>
      <url>file:///EGR-1L11QD2/CLS_lab/fitbir_access_project</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>cls.lab</groupId>
    <artifactId>fitbir_access</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.200</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

My application is connected to a MySQL database, I'm not sure if that has something to do with it.

Edit: Tried to run the following line in both Administrator: Windows PowerShell and Command Prompt, both with the same error "Could not find or load main class: mainWindow.java":

java -jar fitbir_access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Here is MANIFEST.MF Properties:

[image: MANIFEST.MF Properties]

And here is what I get when I try to open MANIFEST.MF:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: audra
Build-Jdk: 16.0.1
Main-Class: mainWindow.java

Edit 2: Here is the file location for mainWindow.java:  C:\Users\audra\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FITBIR\src\main\java\cls_lab\mainWindow.java

Compile classpath: C:\Users\audra.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.24\mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar;C:\Users\audra.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\3.11.4\protobuf-java-3.11.4.jar;C:\Users\audra.m2\repository\com\h2database\h2\1.4.200\h2-1.4.200.jar;C:\Users\audra\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\fitbir\target\classes

Runtime classpath: C:\Users\audra\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\fitbir\target\classes;C:\Users\audra.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.24\mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar;C:\Users\audra.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\3.11.4\protobuf-java-3.11.4.jar;C:\Users\audra.m2\repository\com\h2database\h2\1.4.200\h2-1.4.200.jar

And the boot classpath is like a page long so I won't post it unless it's necessary.

Edit 3: I changed the file locations so everything is under NetBeansProjects\fitbir (with lowercase letters), but this did not solve anything. I also changed the main class name in the pom file to cls_lab.mainWindow.java so that it is now the fully qualified class name, but I still have the same error when I run it through command prompt: Can not find or load main class.

Comment: One observation (not an answer): Does your pom literally say `<mainClass>Your Main Class</mainClass>`? If so, you need to replace `Your Main Class` with the fully qualified class name of your main class (`org.foo.MyClass` or whatever it is called - i.e. the class which contains your `public static void main()` method).

Comment: Oops! Yes, I had copied some code from somewhere and forgot to fill it in. However, the jar file still will not execute, even with the name of the main class.

Comment: Again, this is not an answer, just another observation: You also have `<mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>` - and what appears to be duplicated `<manifest>` sections.

Comment: I removed this, too, when I changed the name of the main class. I don't think there is a duplicate now.

Comment: You can unzip your JAR file to check it contains all its required class files, and that the MANIFEST.MF has the main class set correctly. You can also run it at the command line, of course, to be really sure it runs. After that, you can also take a look at questions such as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/256570/java-jar-files-to-run-on-double-click) which may help for the clickability piece - which will depend on your OS.

Comment: Tried running from command line; it's giving me an error: unable to access jarfile. This is odd because the previous error was "no main manifest attribute," which I then fixed and tried running it again.

Comment: OK - Tried running it how, exactly? You can [edit] your question to provide full details. (Also, unzip the JAR and take a look for yourself to see what it contains.)

Comment: Where is your `mainWindow.java` located? (By the way it violates java naming conventions)